# How can i set Dialog buttons White image?

Tags: android, layout, dialog

This is my Dialog code

```
     AlertDialog.Builder builderofme = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        final FrameLayout frameView = new FrameLayout(this);
        builderofme.setView(frameView);

       builderofme.setCancelable(true);



        builderofme.setPositiveButton(" Yes ", new OkOnClickListener());
        builderofme.setNegativeButton(" No ", new CancelOnClickListener());
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = builderofme.create();
        LayoutInflater inflater = alertDialog.getLayoutInflater();
        View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myediteddialog, frameView);
        alertDialog.show();
```

The Code is working Perfectly.But i want to use the White background for Yes and No button.Presently its coming like this..

[image]

This is my myediteddialog.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/delete"
 >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/editeddialogboxtextview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Do You Want To Delete?"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are using the default theme that's because you are not getting the background color as `Dark holo theme` I would suggest if you want a consistent theme on all the devices then you should declare buttons in the xml file itself and then use it accordingly. This would be the best and right approach in my experience.

Comment: I am using sherlock theme.Its in my activity.how can i use a different theme for the dialog ? i have used the different theme in the xml.somehow its not coming

Comment: This is also the button which is inheritted from default dialog box.I am using alert dialog not the default default dialog

Comment: Is it a must to use AlertDialog if not then I would recommend creating your own dialog and place two buttons it would be more robust and controllable.

Comment: Cool hope i helped you or provided some direction.

Answer (score 0):

you can see the next [example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout).

**Creating a Custom Layout**

If you want a custom layout in a dialog, create a layout and add it to an AlertDialog by calling setView() on your AlertDialog.Builder object.

By default, the custom layout fills the dialog window, but you can still use AlertDialog.Builder methods to add buttons and a title.

Answer (score 0):

Here You can declare the two buttons in the layout files of `myediteddialog.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/delete"
 >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/editeddialogboxtextview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Do You Want To Delete?"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


<Button
        android:id="@+id/stopButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="ffffff"
       android:text="Yes" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="ffffff"
        android:text="No" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in my way using few xml and not changing anything else.Thought to share with you guys who are going for the solution.

First i have created a custom selector drawable xml file for my button

here it is

```
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <item android:state_pressed="true" >
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="3dip" />
         <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#83776b" />
         <gradient  android:angle="-90"  android:startColor="#5f4427" android:endColor="#cbb59d"  />           
     </shape>
 </item>
<item android:state_focused="true">
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="3dip" />
         <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#83776b" />
         <solid  android:color="#92806c"/>      
     </shape>
 </item> 
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="3dip" />
         <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#83776b" />
         <gradient  android:angle="-90"  android:startColor="#cbb59d"    android:endColor="#92806c" />           
     </shape>
   </item>
</selector>
```

Then in my activity i have included this two lines

```
 Button b = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        if(b != null)
                   b.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dialogbutton));

 Button c = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        if(c != null)
                   b.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dialogbutton));
```

Easy solution for me that has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom dialog , here is the best example

[custom dialog](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

Answer (score -1):

As per your requirement u have to design custom dialog layout this layout contains one textview and 2 buttons which look as default alert dialog. and write listeners for two buttons and design buttons according to your requirement .